# $\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f-f_n\|_p=0\implies \lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_p=\|f\|_p$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Suppose $(X,M,\mu)$ is a measure space, $\mu$ a positive measure $f_n,f\in L^{p}(X)$ and $1\leq p < \infty$. I want to prove that

> $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f-f_n\|_p=0\implies 
> \displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\|f_n\|_p=\|f\|_p$

I don't really know how to prove this but I have some ideas.

By the Riesz-Fischer theorem, $\{f_n\}\to f$ in $L^p(X)$ implies that there exists a subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ that converges pointwise a.e to $f$ on $X$. And there is another theorem in Royden's which states that:

> **Theorem 7** Let $E$ be a measurable set and $1\leq p<\infty$. Suppose $\{f_n\}$ is a sequence in $L^p(E)$ that converges pointwise a.e. on $E$ to the function $f$ which belongs to $L^p(E)$. Then
> $$\{f_n\}\to f\ \text{in}\ L^p(E)\ \text{if and only}\ \lim_{n\to\infty}\int_E|f_n|^p=\int_E|f|^p.$$

Does this imply the statement is true? Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For any normed vector space $(V,\|\cdot\|)$, it follows from the triangle inequality that
$$ \lvert\|x\|-\|y\|\rvert\leq \|x-y\| $$
for all $x,y\in V$.

Applying this inequality to $L^p(X)$, we have
$$ \lvert \|f_n\|_p-\|f\|_p\rvert\leq \|f_n-f\|_p$$
hence if $f_n\to f$ in $L^p$ then $\|f_n\|_p\to \|f\|_p$.

Comment: thanks! this looks very simple. But is my answer wrong?

Comment: The theorem in Royden proves a stronger result (if and only if) because it assumes pointwise convergence. For the direction you want, pointwise convergence is not needed.

Comment: But we get pointwise convergence from R-F

Comment: Or rather p.w convergence of a subsequence. Nevermind. Thank you for your help

Comment: Well, then using Royden's theorem as a black box would only give you the convergence you want for a subsequence. In any case, my guess is that Royden's proof of the direction you want is the same as my proof. It's actually the other direction that's more interesting.

Comment: Yes the proof is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: In any normed linear space $|\|x\|-\|y\|| \le \|x-y\|.$

Answer (score 1):

We are dealing the Normed linear space.
 So, please remember this method
$||f_{n}||_{p}=||f_{n}-f+f||_{p}≤||f_{n}-f||_{p}+||f||_{p}.$

$\therefore$$||f_{n}||_{p}-||f||_{p}≤||f_{n}-f||_{p}.$

By the symmetry,
$| ||f_{n}||_{p}-||f||_{p}|≤||f_{n}-f||_{p}.$
We can deduce from this.